# Pull Down UIViewController to Expose an Input Box (text input)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to have a gesture recognizer set that when a user swipes down on a uiviewcontroller, they bring into view a text input that they can submit to change the data on the uiviewcontroller.

How can I do this? I am using storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be to have a view containing the input box with the initial co-ordinates of the view such that its just off the top of the screen. Then when the user swipes down animate the y co-ordindate so that the view appears and scrolls down as the user drags it down.

Comment: I've done this so if you get stuck add a comment. The key is to make it smooth and not jerky using the velocity of the swipe in combination with accelleration/deceleration and animation.

Comment: @Mr H, would you happen to have a sample code of it on github, I'm trying to achieve the same thing but I would like to see if someone has a sample code of it for me to play around with and fit to my liking, thanks